# Joint distribution of $Y_i = \sum_{j=1}^m a_{ij} X_j$ ($i \in \{1,\ldots,n\}$)

Tags: linear-algebra, probability-theory

Let $X_j$ ($j\in\{1,\ldots,m\}$) be $m$ independent continous random variables on $\mathbb{R}$, and

$$Y_i = \sum_{j=1}^m a_{ij} X_j,\quad i\in \{1,\ldots,n\},$$

where $a_{ij} \in {\mathbb R}$. We note that $m \neq n$.

Assume $\mathbf{X} = [X_1, \ldots, X_m]^T$ follows the joint distribution $f_X(x_1,\ldots,x_m)$, and what is the joint distribution of $\mathbf{Y} = [Y_1, \ldots, Y_n]^T$?

Thanks!

PS1: Note that $m \neq n$. For $m = n$, the joint distribution can be derived by using Jacobian matrix.

PS2: The problem has a simplier description when using random vectors $\mathbf{X}$ and $\mathbf{Y}$ with $\mathbf{Y} = \mathbf{A} \mathbf{X}$, where $\mathbf{A} = [a_{ij}]_{n\times m}$ ($m\neq n$).

Comment: Are you looking for a general answer which represent $f_Y$ in terms of $f_X$, $A$ and $n$? If yes, I am afraid there is no such answer. Only if you restrict $X$ to be in a certain class of distributions.

Comment: @Cettt Thanks very much! For Gaussian distribution, $\mathbf{Y}$ can be simply determined by its mean and covariance matrix. Yet, this question would focus on how to derive the distribution of $\mathbf{Y}$ through integrations. There could be a problem on the integral since the dimensions $m$ and $n$ are not equal. Maybe we could use SVD to make the redundant columns (if $m > n$) or rows (if $m < n$) be zeros.